# Creating and saving a database in my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a Windows Forms application in VS 2013 that requires saving data. I can't find a good solution for this, since:

1. A SQL Server database will work fine, but it will force the user
   to have SQL Server installed on their computer.
2. The same applies to Access or Oracle DB.
3. DataSets require a database connection,which leads me to 1) and 3).
4. Text/XML files don't satisfy the
       security requirements and will seem like a very primitive solution.
5. So , in essence, when the user installs the application, on its
   first deployment it must create a database and keep it for future
   access, without requiring the user to have any special programs
   installed (e.g. SQL Server). I apologize if this question seems
   stupid.

Comment: You can take a look at `SQLite`. It doesn't require to install anything

Comment: You could read this about Sql Server Compact http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2007/03/31/creating-your-sql-server-compact-edition-database-and-schema-in-code.aspx

Comment: It's good etiquette to post a response which shows how you solved your problem and indicate how useful the answers provided for you were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in two parts - how to create a database application and how to access it for initialisation.

**Option 1** - if you can resolve the problem of installing SQL Lite/compact using the suggestions above then you can use Entity Framework with code first to create the database and tables. There are plenty of examples only a Google search away.

**Option 2** - create an Access database (an MDB or ACCDB file) with blank/empty tables and deploy this as part of your application. You can the access this with a suitable connection string - again, Google will solve that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Compact Edition .
Using LINQ to SQL you can create a Database/Tables for the first time deployment.

Please Refer the Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you add an example this would be a good answer otherwise it is just nothing more than a comment